# Rails 4: Heroku + Paperclip + s3 not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4.2

so im following this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

I manage to deploy it to Heroku and App is working in the development. The app is running in Heroku but when i try to upload photo. it gives me this page

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

I try to debug it by going to console and typing heroku logs it gives me the following error:

> heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/friends"
>   host=s3friends.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=4173ed9e-ed69-492c-b1b9-d98227ca678c fwd="98.207.140.59"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=2668ms status=500 bytes=1754

Production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

gem file:

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

I've also made sure that the credential on my heroku config match the credential on my s3.

any help would be greatly appreacted.

Comment: did you manage to solve this @Marv-C. i've been struggling to get this to work myself

Comment: @Ben Yes, Ben i managed to make it work. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Add `region` and `s3_host_name`.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"],
      access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
      secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
      s3_region: ENV["S3_REGION"],
      s3_host_name: ENV["S3_HOST_NAME"]
    }
```

S3_REGION="eu-central-1"
S3_HOST_NAME="s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"

Regions and endpoints: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Using `gem "aws-sdk", "~> 2.0"`

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same problem, I solved this by renaming `:bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],` to `:bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],`

and downgrading `gem 'aws-sdk'` to gem `'aws-sdk', '~> 1.61.0'`

and it fix my problem.