# Heroku paperclip demo + local S3 fakes3 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

Trying to get my first s3 app going. Followed the paperclip_demo example but struggling to get local version working with fakes3. Keep getting "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error. In the logs (set to debug level), I get error

```
        Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "testme.fakes3.local" port 443):
```

biggest issue is that it seems not to connect to the correct port. (config file (`development.rb`) below)

```
        # /etc/hosts
        127.0.0.1      fakes3.local testme.fakes3.local
```

running fakes3 as

`fakes3 -r /tmp/fakes3 -p 4567 -H fakes3.local`

I've tried

- s3_port v just port
- string versus numeric
- inside :s3_credentials, or outside, or in s3_options hash
- I'm confused by this [aws blog](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxVOTODBPHAEP9/Working-with-Regions)awsblog post which suggests its not s3_port but just "port"
- tried adding s3_endpoint (or just endpoint) (as per this [aws blog](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3/issues/32))

  ```
    # development.rb

    config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_protocol => 'http',
      :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => "testme",
        :access_key_id => "blah",
        :secret_access_key => "blah"
      },
        :s3_host_name => "fakes3.local", # also added s3_endpoint
        :port => 4567, # tried s3_port, tried string and just numeric
        :use_ssl => false
    }
  ```

**UPDATE**

I did try

- downgrading the aws-sdk as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098534/rails-4-heroku-paperclip-s3-not-working-in-production).
- using port 443 - this does not work as the web server is running on this so there is a conflict

Comment: check the port port 443

Comment: sorry do you mean set port to 443 (tried that) or something else?